Filter Function on list
I have a table that I am trying to use the filter function to report the names based on last names and the priority level. Currently I am able to use the filter function to look at a specific name in a drop down but it does not do it based on priority.
The list currently has 59 values and I am trying to cut down the time it takes and create an easier way to look based on the priority levels. I do have other criteria it is looking (date ranges attached to the names). I am not able to manipulate the data on Table1 due to legalities.
Right now I am using this filter formula:
=FILTER(Table1[Names],ISNUMBER(SEARCH(I1,Table1[Names])))


I'm not sure if the filter function is the best tool or if there is a better suggestion, my VBA usage is very restricted.
This is the formula close to what I am trying to get working on a sample set of data:
=FILTER(Table1[Names],ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Table2[Last],Table1[Names]))*(Table2[Priority]=I1))

So if I wanted to input "High" in I1 it would return as such:

Table1:



Names




Wanda Hayden


Olin Valentine


Harriet Gonzales


Wilfredo Shah


Deshawn Levy


Tanner Avila


Keneth Howe


Chung Hayes


Glenda Cardenas


Laverne Briggs


Jonah Potter


Lyle Gregory


Micheal Reyes


Al Hunter


Normand Bowers


Brock Patrick


Royal Arellano


Ernestine Henry


Armand Arias



Table2:



First
Last
Priority




Brock
Patrick
High


Tanner
Avila
Low


Wilfredo
Shah
High


Chung
Hayes
High


Olin
Valentine
Low


Lyle
Gregory
High


Deshawn
Levy
Low



Output Based on High (Cell I1)



High




Wilfredo Shah


Chung Hayes


Lyle Gregory


Brock Patrick




@rotabor as I explained on the solution I accepted, it works in tandem with other lookups. That negates the need to look first & last which is why in my post I specified the last name/priority level need.

There is nothing wrong with your formula, but in the SEARCH() function, find_text and within_text both are vertical, one or the other needs to be either vertical or horizontal, one other reason has already been mentioned by @ScottCraner Sir :


• One alternative using BYROW():
=FILTER(Table1[Names],
 BYROW(1-ISERR(SEARCH(TOROW(FILTER(Table2[Last],I1=Table2[Priority],"")),Table1[Names])),LAMBDA(α,OR(α))))


• Or, without using LAMBDA() helper function:
=CHOOSEROWS(Table1[Names],
SORT(XMATCH("*"&FILTER(Table2[Last],Table2[Priority]=I1),
Table1[Names],2)))


Or,
=FILTER(Table1[Names],
 IFNA(SIGN(XLOOKUP(Table1[Names],
 Table2[First]&" "&Table2[Last],Table2[Priority])=I1),0))


There are many ways of doing this, and since you are specifically looking for the Last_Names in the Names Column, adding another alternative:
=FILTER(Table1[Names],
 ISNUMBER(XMATCH(TEXTAFTER(Table1[Names]," ",-1),
 FILTER(Table2[Last],Table2[Priority]=I1,""))))



Other formulas

=FILTER(
  Table1[Names],
  BYROW(
    TEXTAFTER(Table1[Names]," ",-1)=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Table2[Last],Table2[Priority]=I1,"")),
    LAMBDA(row,OR(row))
  )
)


=TOCOL(
  IFS(
    TEXTAFTER(Table1[Names]," ",-1)=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(Table2[Last],Table2[Priority]=I1,"")),
    Table1[Names]
  ),
  2
)


=FILTER(Table1[Names],1-ISNA(XMATCH(Table1[Names],FILTER(Table2[First]&" "&Table2[Last],Table2[Priority]=I1))))
Note that your data doesn't use middle names. Is that troublesome?

With transposed array argument, SEARCH will give the result in multiple columns. These can then be merged with MMULT. Just giving another approach for possible future use.
=LET(
    last_to_match, FILTER(Table2[Last], Table2[Priority] = $I$2),
    FILTER(
        Table1,
        MMULT(
            --ISNUMBER(
                SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(last_to_match), Table1[Names])
            ),
            SEQUENCE(ROWS(last_to_match))
        )
    )
)


